# problem with creating new columns inside a data frame by using function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, vector

I have this dataframe

```
a <- data.frame(b = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                d = c(2,4,6,8,10,12))
```

I want to make a make another row f which would be (d-b). How can I do this using a fucntion? I tried

```
new_a <- function(data, col1, col2){
  data$f <- data$col2 - data$col1
  return(data)
}
```

which gave " Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, c, value = integer(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 5 "

I also tried

```
  new_a = function(data, col1, col2) {
    data$f = data[col1] - data[col2]
    return(data)
  }
```

but this table wont name the new row as "f"

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: You need `data[f] = data[col1] - data[col2]`

Comment: You can adjust this line: `data$f <- data[[col2]] - data[[col1]]`, and then call `new_a(data, "b", "d")`

Answer (score 1):

In your data frame, if there are no columns named `col1` and `col2`, you will get that error. Using your example and changing your `new_a` function worked as follows,

```
new_a <- function(data){
  data$f <- data$d - data$b
  return(data)
}
```